# Is their an way to not refresh or load the entire page when user is navigating?

Tags: wordpress, internet-radio

I am building a WordPress website for an radio station. They want to integrate the streaming option into the header and give user the ability to navigate their site without taget_blank or _blank and keep streaming.

So basically they would like users to listening to their radio without putting the streaming window in a popup or any other window what is not the landing page.

Only think i could think is to not refresh or load the entire new page while user is surfing and leave the header fix.

Does anybody has any idea how to get this done?

Appreciate the gesture.

I found a solution based on Frameset, but I think their must be something better, maybe ajax or something.

Comment: This could be implemented with a SPA (Single Page Application). I have no idea if that's possible with wordpress.

Comment: It is possible as WordPress has its own REST API which you can use to build a SPA. OP will have to do some homework to learn how though.

Comment: Thanks Mickers and cabrerahector your points of view where very helpful. Also what cabrerahector said about the REST API helped a lot. Now the client needs to think what and how he want to get this done.

Thanks for the input!